# How to set date and internal image in one recyclerview in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, image-gallery, android-gallery

I'm creating a gallery app in android studio. I have to set image and image captured date in one single recycler view like this image........
[this is example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf5ta.jpg)

can you give me some hint?

Comment: This needs a lot of programming logic to take care of. I can't write code for you. Your pictures need to have a date when they are taken, you need to check if the dates are equal, and so on. Why don't you try to implement something and then come back with the question if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: @SlothCoding see this is code to i trying to create..[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757866/grouping-images-by-date-in-recyclerview-in-androidstudio)